# How to avoid digest cycle delay from two-way binding

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

### Angularjs when two way data binding is triggered?

In an AngularJS application I have a parent directive and a child directive.

### parentDirective

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('customForm', function(customService, apiV1, Constants, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        param1: '=',
        param2: '=?',
        boolean1: '@?'
      },
      template,
      link: function(scope, parentController) {
      scope.data = customService.newClient;
      //some stuff...
```

### childDirective JS:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('customToolForm', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
        city: '=',
        postalCode: '='
      },
      template,
      controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, Constants, apiV1, customService) {

     $scope.doSomethingWithPostalCode = function() {
         $scope.$parent.doSomethingWithPostalCode();
     }
     //some stuff...
```

### parentDirective HTML piece:

```
<address-client-creation name="data.client.name" city="data.client.city"
                         postal-code="data.client.postalCode">
</address-client-creation>
```

### childDirective HTML piece :

```
 <input maxlength="5" type="text" data-ng-model="postalCode"
        data-ng-change="doSomethingWithPostalCode();">
```

The issue I have is that :

When the method `doSomethingWithPostalCode` is triggered from the childDirective, the value of the postalCode in the child is not the same as the client.postalCode of the parent, but at the end of the method it is.

**it seems that the two way binding event that update the parent value is happening after the function call**

So my question is what is the best way to ensure that the $parent scope is updated before calling the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to avoid digest cycle delay from two-way binding

The AngularJS framework implements two-way (`'='`) binding by adding a watcher to the child scope which transfer the data from the child scope to the parent scope. The watcher requires a digest cycle to detect the change and do the transfer.

A more modern approach is to use one-way (`"<"`) binding for inputs and expression (`"&"`) binding for outputs:

```
app.directive('customToolForm', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '<',
        city: '<',
        ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶a̶l̶C̶o̶d̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶
        postalCode: '<',
        postalCodeChange: '&',
      },
      template: `
          <input maxlength="5" type="text" data-ng-model="postalCode"
                 data-ng-change="doSomethingWithPostalCode(postalCode);">
      `,
      controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, Constants, apiV1, customService) {

     $scope.doSomethingWithPostalCode = function(postalCode) {
         ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶p̶a̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶d̶o̶S̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶W̶i̶t̶h̶P̶o̶s̶t̶a̶l̶C̶o̶d̶e̶(̶)̶;̶
         $scope.postalCodeChange({$event: postalCode});
     }
     //some stuff...
```

Usage:

```
<custom-form-tool 
    name="data.client.name" city="data.client.city"
    postal-code="data.client.postalCode"
    postal-code-change="data.client.postalCode=$event; doSomething($event)"
>
</custom-form-tool>
```

Using expression (`"&"`) binding immediately makes the event data available to the parent controller.

It also makes the migration path to Angular 2+ easier.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [Angular 2+ Developer Guide - 2 Way Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

Comment: Ok thanks that is clear. In the meantime I found a "solution", using $scope.$watch(postalCode) it seemed that the binding were updated first. Do you think it is a good enough solution ? @georgeawg

Comment: Post your solution and I will tell you what I think about it. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to use `$watch` in the **childDirective**:

```
    /**
     * Using $watch instead of data-ng-change ensure that bindings are updated
     */
    $scope.$watch('postalCode', function() {
       $scope.$parent.doSomethingWithPostalCode();
    });
```

And so removing `the data-ng-change` on the input of the child directive :

```
 <input maxlength="5" type="text" data-ng-model="postalCode">
```

When debugging inside the $watch method, I could verify that the parent $scope was already updated.

Not sure if it is a real solution or more like a hack.

Comment: Use of `$scope.$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. In this case it hardwires the component to a specific method in the parent controller. Use of expression (`"&"`) binding allows users of the component to bind to any method in the parent controller. Also `$scope.$watch` is not available in Angular 2+ apps. This will make the migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.